VSCode Logic App func.exe Service Bus Transport Type
Can i change the Azure Service Bus transport type used by func?
I ran c:\Users\xxxx.azurelogicapps\dependencies\FuncCoreTools\func host start --verbose
and I observed the following in the output:
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.806Z] ServiceBusOptions
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.808Z] {
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.808Z]   "ClientRetryOptions": {
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.809Z]     "Mode": "Exponential",
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.809Z]     "TryTimeout": "00:01:00",
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.810Z]     "Delay": "00:00:00.8000000",
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.810Z]     "MaxDelay": "00:01:00",
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.811Z]     "MaxRetries": 3
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.811Z]   },
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.812Z]   "TransportType": "AmqpTcp",
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.812Z]   "WebProxy": "",
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.813Z]   "AutoCompleteMessages": true,
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.813Z]   "PrefetchCount": 0,
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.814Z]   "MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration": "00:05:00",
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.814Z]   "MaxConcurrentCalls": 128,
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.815Z]   "MaxConcurrentSessions": 8,
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.815Z]   "MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession": 1,
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.816Z]   "MaxMessageBatchSize": 1000,
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.816Z]   "MinMessageBatchSize": 1,
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.817Z]   "MaxBatchWaitTime": "00:00:30",
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.817Z]   "SessionIdleTimeout": "",
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.818Z]   "EnableCrossEntityTransactions": false
[2024-05-16T12:41:47.818Z] }

Note "TransportType": "AmqpTcp".
I know our corporate firewall will not allow traffic on 5671,5672 but is OK with 443.
Ultimately i want to run a Logic App in VSCode (which uses fun.exe)
Is there a way I can configure the transport type used by func (in VSCode) to use AMQP over web sockets i.e. port 443?

try adding "extensions": {     "serviceBus": {       "transportType": "amqpWebSockets"     }   } in host.json file

Ikhtesam is correct.   Service Bus configuration settings are documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings

You can set the value of TransportType in host.json file as shown below.
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "concurrency": {
    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
    "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "transportType": "amqpWebSockets"
    }
  }
}

In order to set the port, you need to use webProxy in host.json.
"extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "transportType": "amqpWebSockets",
      "webProxy": "<proxy address and port>"
    }
  }

I am getting below output.

Please refer to the MS Doc to know more about the host.json settings.

The comment from Ikhtesam Afrin is the solution. Thanks Ikhtesam
in host.json add the "serviceBus": {
"transportType": "amqpWebSockets" }
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "workflow": {
      "settings": {
        "Runtime.WorkflowOperationDiscoveryHostMode": "true"
      }
    },
    "serviceBus": {
      "transportType": "amqpWebSockets"
  }
  }
}

